# Set Span (Especially AbsoluteSizeSpan) at Empty EditText

Tags: java, android, spannable

How can I Set Span (Especially AbsoluteSizeSpan) at Empty `EditText`?
I can make it if there's only one letter, but I can't make if there's no letter.

Also, I wanna ask you some question :

```
for (AbsoluteSizeSpan as : spannable.getSpans(k, k + 1, AbsoluteSizeSpan.class)) {

        Log.d(TAG, "spannable.getSpans.length:" + spannable.getSpans(k, k + 1, AbsoluteSizeSpan.class).length);
        Log.d(TAG, "sizeSpans(" + k + "):" + as.toString());
        if (!selectedItem.equals("")) {
               spannable.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(Integer.parseInt(selectedItem), true), k, k + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
               spannable.removeSpan(as); // 서식 지우고
         }
}
```